# SSH as Normal User --> SU --> SCP as Root

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, winscp, su

I'm on a Win7 box connecting to a linux server.

From reading: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su it looks like I need to open my SCP connections as the particular user.

When I connect via SSH, I can use su and then see all the files I need on the system.

I would like to know if there is a program I can use that will allow me to connect via SSH and then open an SCP connection with those elevated privileges. I would prefer something with a GUI, such as WinSCP.

Comment: Root login is disabled? It might also help if you explain why you want to do this, maybe there are alternatives.

Comment: the very best answer is to make sure that the files you need are accessible to the user who needs them, eg you.

Comment: @DanielBeck, yes root ssh is disabled by design, so I have to su after I connect. I will do as Frank suggests, if there is no way to do what I requested.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the exact link you have posted shows you how to "connect via SSH and then open an SCP connection with those elevated privileges".

I believe that there is no other/better way. Actually I do not know of any other file transfer client that allows this. And if there is, it can hardly do it other way.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing root logons directly via password is definitely a security risk. I'd say the best way is to use `sudo`.